# get full path of file in cordova while using input type file

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

i am using file transfer object to upload file.
for upload function  i a have to pass file Path parameter. 
I am passing that parameter but getting error code 1.
here is my code

```
<input type="file" style="display:none;"  id="file-selector" onchange = "angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this)"></input> 

var server = encodeURI(someUrl);
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
options.fileName = "name";
options.mimeType = "text/plain";
options.chunkedMode = false;
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.upload(filePath,server,onSuccess,onFailure,options,true);
```

Comment: if you use input file you won't get a valid url, you have to send the form data to the server using AJAX, not file-transfer plugin. If you want to use file-transfer plugin then use a file picker/file chooser plugin instead of the input file

Comment: but is there no another way to do this using file input only?

Comment: sending the information to the server using AJAX  instead of using file-transfer